# Why my elbow function is not defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I successfully created my function but when I call it I get the error:

> not defined function ' elbow'

What's wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist

def eblow(df,n):
    kMeansVar = [KMeans(n_clusters=NUM_CLUSTERS, n_jobs=1, random_state=0, n_init=1, verbose=True).fit(df) for k in range(1, n)]
    centroids = [X.cluster_centers_ for X in kMeansVar]
    k_euclid = [cdist(df, cent) for cent in centroids]
    dist = [np.min(ke, axis=1) for ke in k_euclid]
    wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
    tss = sum(pdist(df)**2)/df.shape[0]
    bss = tss - wcss
    plt.plot(bss)
plt.show()

X=np.random.rand(60,45)
el=elbow(X,30)
```

Comment: call elbow(np.random.rand(60,45), 6)

Comment: Check the name letter by letter. It looks like you’ve made a typo in the name of the function.

Comment: This question should be closed. The only reason for this question was a typo.

Answer (score 4):

You defined eblow but I don't see a function elbow.